# If the thing is named, do we have to use "it", or it will depend on something?

Tags: pronouns

I need help please, I know it is a basic thing but as a Spanish speaker I have always had problems with the correct use of "it".
For example:

> That green skirt belongs to Anne, **it** is her skirt.

In the last section of that sentence, if I name the thing (skirt), do I still have to use "it"?   Because there are cases when the "it" can be left out, right?

Comment: Do you mean to say that in Spanish, we can write "That green skirt belongs to Annie, is her skirt"?

Comment: "That green skirt belongs to Anne, it is her skirt." is grammatically acceptable. It could also be changed into "that green skirt belongs to Anne, it is hers."

Comment: "It" is anaphoric to "that green skirt". We call it a pro-form. You can omit "it", but you get the repetitive "That green skirt belongs to Anne; that green skirt is her skirt. The whole idea of pro-forms like "it" is to avoid unnecessary repetition. Have you got an example of "it" being left out?

Comment: @CowperKettle - Yes, in Spanish you can often omit an explicit pronoun, or you can regard it as included in the verb: *Es mi abrigo* = "It's my coat."  You don't usually have to say "Él es" or "Ella es" unless it's really necessary for clarification.

Comment: @stangdon - interesting! In Russian, we never use the verb in this sentence. "It my coat". It is called "zero copula" (нулевая связка): the copular "is" is implied but not pronounced.

Answer (score 3):

In English, apart from imperatives and some informal conversational patterns (see below), we always need a subject, even if it is the formally meaningless "it" or "there" (as in "It's raining", or "There is a book on the table"). In your example, "it" isn't meaningless, it refers to the skirt, and is required.

The informal conversational patterns I referred to are harder to characterise. In answering a question, we can sometimes omit the subject:

> Why is he here?
>   Wants to ask you something.

but it is more common to omit the subject and auxiliary:

> Where's Jackie?
>   Gone home.

Sometimes in a sort of spoken narrative, the subject can be omitted when it's obvious, but this is nearly always a first or second person subject:

> Went down to the shops yesterday: bought a sofa.
>
> Forgot something?

But here too, we often drop an auxiliary as well as the subject:

> Been away, then? 
>   Yes, visiting the Bahamas.

And I have had difficulty inventing a plausible third-person example, unless it follows a sentence where the subject is expressed:

> She left home last Thursday. Went to London, apparently.

And I can't think of any plausible example of omitting a subject before a part of "be", except maybe in an argument:

> You weren't there! Was!

In summary, I can't think of any context in which "Is her skirt" would stand as a sentence (not a question!) on its own.

Comment: Q: "Her shoes are green." A: "Is her skirt?" Clumsy, agreed, but one might hear it in conversation.

Comment: @P.E.Dant: "Is her skirt?" is a perfectly normal question, with the verb 'is' inverted before the subject. The subject is present. I'll edit the reply.

Comment: Mr. Colin Fine, thank you for your answer. If I understood well, you say that it is possible in this case to leave "it" out: "Is her skirt"  Is this correct? It seems that you are the only person who thinks like this. All the other people who had the kindness to send a reply, think otherwise. A bit confusing, is it not?

Comment: No, @claudiosepulveda. I said that "Is her skirt?" is a well-formed **question**, but I didn't say that it only makes sense if the context shows what you're asking about her skirt, as in P.E.Dant's example. As a statement, "Is her skirt" is ungrammatical.